# Unknown provider in Karma test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

I have the following provider:

```
(function (angular) {
  angular.module('app')
        .provider('$_Config', ConfigProvider);

  function ConfigProvider() {
      .... //routes definition 
  }
  ConfigProvider.prototype.$get = function () {
    return this;
  };

  ConfigProvider.prototype.getRoutes = function() {...}

  //other prototype functions 

})(angular);
```

In app.js I am using it like this:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $_ConfigProvider) {
    var routes = $_ConfigProvider.getRoutes();
    routes.forEach(function(route) {
        $routeProvider
          .when(route.route, {
           .....
          })

}
```

Every thing work fine till it gets to testing. Here is my test:

```
describe('Provider: $_ConfigProvider', function () {

  // load the providers module
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  // instantiate provider
  var $_ConfigProvider;
  beforeEach(inject(function (_$_Config_) {
    $_ConfigProvider = _$_Config_;
  }));


  it('Should verify getRoutes function', function () {
    var routes = $_ConfigProvider.getRoutes();
    expect(Object.prototype.toString.call(routes) === '[object Array]').toBe(true);
  });
});
```

When running the test I am getting the following error:

```
  Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
  Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $_ConfigProvider
```

**Note:** The `$_ConfigProvider` is injected correctly during run-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely not including the file where the provider is defined in in your karma.conf.js dependencies list. See this question:

[Include dependencies in Karma test file for Angular app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132823/include-dependencies-in-karma-test-file-for-angular-app)

I would rename the $_Config to something else, '$' is usually reserved for angular-specific components.

Comment: @vlio20 ordering what exactly?

Comment: The static resources, your 3rd party libs.